# Inheriting class javadoc

Tags: java, inheritance, javadoc

Are you able to have a subclass inherit a superclass's class javadoc?
Something like this:

```
/**
 * Parent javadoc
 */
class Superclass {}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 * Child javadoc
 */
class Subclass extends Superclass {}
```

Comment: Not as far as I know. For me, this also seems pointless. The `Subclass` has something that makes it unique. This uniqueness should be reflected in the class's javadoc.

Comment: I hear what you're saying. For me, the subclass is doing what the superclass does but in a specific way so it made sense for me to just write one description about what the class does in the main class and have the subclass inherit that and then put in a little but more about some of the specific details about what the specific subclass is doing.

Comment: "*For me, the subclass is doing what the superclass does but in a specific way...*" - For me, this sounds like something worth documenting.

Comment: I agree. What I'm saying is that I want to add this specific documentation for this subclass in addition to the documentation I have on the superclass.
That's what I meant by _"and then put in a little but [sic] more about some of the specific details about what the specific subclass is doing"_

Comment: Like if I had a Car superclass with a javadoc of "this is a 4-wheeled vehicle with an engine" and a subclass of Taxi, I would want the subclass to have the superclass javadoc and then add in "used by drivers to pick-up and drop people off".

Comment: Much more readable doc is to mention **only the differences** against the superclass, rather than to copy the whole documentation. The user can always click on the Javadoc for the superclass. Of course you may put there a sentence like `The class is doing the same as {@link Superclass}, with the following differences:`, then the superclass doc is directly clickable.